# I want to save results in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make the system, when I put email address and password in database, these datas are sent to Controller and these are saved in Model.

I wrote codes in migrate file like

```
class CreateUserdata < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :userdata do |t|
    　t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

in Model like

```
class Userdatum < ActiveRecord::Base
    user = User.new
    user.attributes = {name : "Yuri", :email : "odyssey"}
    user.save
end
```

in Controller like

```
class ConnectionController <  ActiveRecord::Base
    def index
        @user = User.all
        render :json => user
    end
end
```

However, I'm a beginner so I think these codes are wrong but I don't know how to fix it. How should I fix it?

I want to put password and email address in DB of a server.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that in model.
Model should only contain information about model. 
If you want to load test data into model.Put these lines into `db/seeds.rb` file. 
Then run `rake db:seed`.

```
user = User.new
user.name = "Yuri"
user.email = "odyssey"
user.save
```

You could use `rails console` to check it exists.

Ref: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data